# Integrate Autobahn|Python with aiohttp

Tags: python, autobahn, aiohttp, crossbar, wamp-protocol

I'm trying to integrate an `aiohttp` web server into a Crossbar+Autobahn system architecture.

More in detail, when the `aiohttp` server receive a certain API call, it has to publish a message to a Crossbar router.
I've seen [this example](https://github.com/crossbario/autobahn-python/blob/master/examples/asyncio/wamp/pubsub/basic/backend.py) on the official repos but i've no clue on how to integrate it on my application.

Ideally, i would like to be able to do this

```
# class SampleTaskController(object):
async def handle_get_request(self, request: web.Request) -> web.Response:
    self.publisher.publish('com.myapp.topic1', 'Hello World!')
    return web.HTTPOk()
```

where `self` il an instance of `SampleTaskController(object)` which defines all the routes handler of the web server.

```
def main(argv):
    cfg_path = "./task_cfg.json"
    if len(argv) > 1:
        cfg_path = argv[0]

    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                        format=LOG_FORMAT)

    loop = zmq.asyncio.ZMQEventLoop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

    app = web.Application(loop=loop)
    with open(cfg_path, 'r') as f:
        task_cfg = json.load(f)
        task_cfg['__cfg_path'] = cfg_path
        controller = SampleTaskController(task_cfg)
        controller.restore()
        app['controller'] = controller

        controller.setup_routes(app)

        app.on_startup.append(controller.on_startup)
        app.on_cleanup.append(controller.on_cleanup)
        web.run_app(app,
                    host=task_cfg['webserver_address'],
                    port=task_cfg['webserver_port'])
```

Notice that i'm using an `zmq.asyncio.ZMQEventLoop` because the server is also listening on a `zmq` socket, which is configured inside the `controller.on_startup` method.

Instead of using autobahn, i've also tried to publish the message to Crossbar using `wampy` and it works, but the autobahn subscribers couldn't correctly parse the message.

```
# autobahn subscriber
class ClientSession(ApplicationSession):
    async def onJoin(self, details):

        self.log.info("Client session joined {details}", details=details)

        self.log.info("Connected:  {details}", details=details)

        self._ident = details.authid
        self._type = u'Python'

        self.log.info("Component ID is  {ident}", ident=self._ident)
        self.log.info("Component type is  {type}", type=self._type)

        # SUBSCRIBE

        def gen_on_something(thing):
            def on_something(counter, id, type):
                print('----------------------------')
                self.log.info("'on_{something}' event, counter value: {message}",something=thing, message=counter)
                self.log.info("from component {id} ({type})", id=id, type=type)
            return on_something

        await self.subscribe(gen_on_something('landscape'), 'landscape')
        await self.subscribe(gen_on_something('nature'), 'nature')
```

-

```
# wampy publisher
async def publish():
    router = Crossbar(config_path='./crossbar.json')
    logging.getLogger().debug(router.realm)
    logging.getLogger().debug(router.url)
    logging.getLogger().debug(router.port)

    client = Client(router=router)
    client.start()

    result = client.publish(topic="nature", message=0)
    logging.getLogger().debug(result)
```

With this configuration the subscriber receive the message published, but it get an exception while parsing it.

```
TypeError: on_something() got an unexpected keyword argument 'message'
```

Comment: You can instantiate a `ClientSession` object `mySessionObject` globally (or put it onto the app object of your Web app), then instaniate an `ApplicationRunner` and call `run(make=mySessionObject, start_loop=False)`, and then use the session object inside your Web route handler to publish an event. We probably should have that as an example ..

Comment: @oberstet I've tried what you've suggested, but when i try to publish a message i got a `TransportLost` exception. [Gist of the code](https://gist.github.com/GiacomoManzoli/ee9a1a475e0b0f767a3aa8ad445e0e10) when i run it, there is the default Crossabar image running inside a Docker container and the Autobahn|Python example works correctly, so it shouldn't be an enviroment problem.

Comment: @oberstet i think i've found the example you are referencing https://github.com/crossbario/autobahn-python/blob/master/examples/asyncio/wamp/component/backend.py but i'm unable to run it, because the autobahn|python installed form pip doesn't have the `autobahn.asyncio.component` module

Comment: The components are not released yet. They just have been merged: https://github.com/crossbario/autobahn-python/pull/872/files#diff-87b06272782923eeb1d608f4202ccbdd
Should be part of the next release.
Anyway, this new API is unrelated to the problem you have.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I tried to use aiohttp and autobahn simultaneously. I reworked the example from crossbar documentation (originally using twisted) and got the following code:

```
import asyncio
import logging

from aiohttp import web
from aiohttp.web_exceptions import HTTPOk, HTTPInternalServerError
from autobahn.asyncio.component import Component

# Setup logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class WebApplication(object):
    """
    A simple Web application that publishes an event every time the
    url "/" is visited.
    """

    count = 0

    def __init__(self, app, wamp_comp):
        self._app = app
        self._wamp = wamp_comp
        self._session = None  # "None" while we're disconnected from WAMP router

        # associate ourselves with WAMP session lifecycle
        self._wamp.on('join', self._initialize)
        self._wamp.on('leave', self._uninitialize)

        self._app.router.add_get('/', self._render_slash)

    def _initialize(self, session, details):
        logger.info("Connected to WAMP router (session: %s, details: %s)", session, details)
        self._session = session

    def _uninitialize(self, session, reason):
        logger.warning("Lost WAMP connection (session: %s, reason: %s)", session, reason)
        self._session = None

    async def _render_slash(self, request):
        if self._session is None:
            return HTTPInternalServerError(reason="No WAMP session")
        self.count += 1
        self._session.publish(u"com.myapp.request_served", self.count, count=self.count)
        return HTTPOk(text="Published to 'com.myapp.request_served'")


def main():
    REALM = "crossbardemo"
    BROKER_URI = "ws://wamp_broker:9091/ws"
    BIND_ADDR = "0.0.0.0"
    BIND_PORT = 8080

    logging.basicConfig(
        level='DEBUG',
        format='[%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(name)s:%(lineno)d]: %(message)s')

    logger.info("Starting aiohttp backend at %s:%s...", BIND_ADDR, BIND_PORT)
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    component = Component(
        transports=BROKER_URI,
        realm=REALM,
    )
    component.start(loop=loop)

    # When not using run() we also must start logging ourselves.
    import txaio
    txaio.start_logging(level='info')

    app = web.Application(
        loop=loop)

    _ = WebApplication(app, component)

    web.run_app(app, host=BIND_ADDR, port=BIND_PORT)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```